# Should I be fetching my Core Data more often?

Tags: iphone, core-data

So right now when my app starts I get all of my data from Core Data. My data has entities of Groups and People. The Groups contain People. So as I go through the app I'm adding and deleting People and Groups.

My problem lies when I select a Group from a tableview and I pass that Group onto the next tableview. From that tableview I can press a button/row and add a bunch of People from a modal view. When I press Done from that modal view I need it to update the previous view with those new People, which it's not doing correctly.

It seems a little, for lack of a better word, wrong that I'm passing a lot of stuff around. Would it be better for me to use another fetch after I update People in a Group? From reading what other people say, then I could have different views listen for an updated Core Data and change their views accordingly.

I really hope this makes sense. I've been reading a lot to try to figure out the best approach but I'm not getting anything definite. I feel like my code is turning into spaghetti so I stopped and I'm trying to rethink it all. I'm also thinking maybe I need my very own Model class as opposed to just the classes that Core Data auto-generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've written what you're doing sounds about right. I assume you're using a NSFetchedResultsController. Have you implemented the [delegate methods outlined in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)? Specifically, the `controllerWillChangeContent`: method should give you what you're after.

Regarding implementing your own NSManagedObject subclass, take a look at [MOGenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/).

Comment: I'll read those docs again but I don't think they'll work for my situation. I have 3 stacked views. My 1st view takes an object from core data and passes it to my 2nd view. The 2nd view takes that object and extracts all the People from it and puts them into a sorted array which fills the table. The issue I have is when I add more People using my 3rd view. I can add them just fine to core data but I'm not sure how to pass this array of People to my 2nd view so that they get updated in the table. How does my 2nd view know which data to use? The data passed from the 1st view or the 2nd view?

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController monitors core-data and will notify you (via the delegate methods) if an object has been inserted, modified, or deleted that matches the current query (or predicate).  In your delegate methods you just need to handle the insertion, update, or delete.  You don't need to worry about "passing back" the new person - NSFetchedResultsController will detect the change for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend NSFetchedResultsController to you. See documentation at ...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Look at CoreDataBooks example, especially at RootViewController.m at ...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405-Classes_RootViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_14

NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate can help you to update your previous view easily. As I wrote, look at sample code to see how it really works.

Comment: I've been referring to CoreDataBooks a lot for this app. Unfortunately, CoreDataBooks example doesn't help with my issue because of the multiple ways I'm allowing users to add People to Groups. It did help me figure out how to make a separate context and then merge them later on. That was key.

Comment: See @chris comment. As he said, NSFetchedResultsController monitors updates (also delete, insert) and you don't need to pass new people to your 2nd view. Just save your changes, merge context and implement NSFetchedResultsController's delegate in your 2nd view to handle these changes.